# Javascript AppendTo Animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am moving child divs from one parent to the other using appendTo. Here is that part of the functions:

```
$('#forum_holder_hidden').children().slice(0,5).appendTo("#forum_holder").fadeIn(8000);
```

This is the html output of the two divs:

```
echo '<div id="outside-one">';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="1"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="2"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="3"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="4"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="5"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="6"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="7"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="8"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="9"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="10"></div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="outside-two">';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="11"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="12"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="13"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="14"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="15"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="16"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="17"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="18"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="19"></div>';
    echo '<div class="inside" id="20"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

The second parent (id = outside-two ) has the css property display:none. I am moving the child divs from the second parent to the first one to display them when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

It doesn't matter what duration or what animation i use at the end it will still change nothing.
Am i doing something wrong here or does the animation not work at all when i am using appendTo?

Comment: Would you share your HTML code too, please? What is going wrong? The element is being added and shown but the animation doesnt? Be more especific please

Comment: I just posted the html code. I take some child divs from the second parent and put them into the first one to display them because the second parent has a display:none. Moving them works just fine but the animation is not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that for any "appearing" animation, the element must be `display:none` before the animation starts. Try setting that before you run the animation.

```
$('#forum_holder_hidden').children().slice(0,5).appendTo("#forum_holder").css('display','none').fadeIn(8000);
```